# Is set of three linear equations with three unknown solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

I have the following set of linear equations with the unknowns $h, n, i$ which I would like to express as a function of my known quantities, $e, f, g$:

$$
e = h - n\\
f = h - i\\
g = i -n
$$

with the constraint $0 \leq h, n, i \leq 1$.

Unfortunately, any type of simplification I tried lead to $0 = 0$. Is this system uniquely solvable or not? If uniquely solvable, I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: If you get $0=0$ that probably means there are infinitely many solutions.  You worry if you get $0=1$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Then perhaps I am interested in uniquely solvable? I just need $h, n, i$ as a function of $e, f, g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is, your equations are not linearly independent, since you have $(2)+(3)=(1)$. This means that you can pick arbitrarily one of the variables $h$, $i$ or $n$, and only then will the other two follow by your system of equations.

Notice that you can derive an additional constraint on your known parameters, namely that $f+g=e$.

Comment: The coefficient matrix has rank $2$, so in fact this additional constraint is sufficient too: Given any triple $(e, f, g)$ satisfying $e = f + g$ there is (by the Rank-Nullity Theorem) always a one-dimensional subspace of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is solvable - and has infinitely many solutions - but sometimes it is not.  It depends on the values of $e,f$ and $g$.
In particular, if there is a solution then $h-i+i-n+n-h=f+g-e=0$.
In that case, $h$ can be anything, say $=x$, then $n=x-e$ and $i=x-f$

Comment: I need this for a situation (i.e., a model) in which I do not know the value of $e, f,$ and $g$. Then this might mean, I may need to rethink my problem.